# Using a Docker secret for accessing database in Jenkinsfile

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, docker-secrets

In my `Jenkinsfile` I'm running a Maven command to start a database migration. This database is running in a Docker container.

When deploying the database container we're using a Docker secret from the swarm manager node for the password.

Is there any way how to ***use that Docker secret in the Jenkins pipeline script*** instead of putting it in in plain text? I could use Jenkins credentials but then I'd need to maintain the same secrets in two different places.

```
sh """$mvn flyway:info \
    -Dproject.host=$databaseHost \
    -Dproject.port=$databasePort \
    -Dproject.schema=$databaseSchema \
    -Dproject.user=db_user \
    -Dproject.password=db_pass \ // <--- Use a Docker secret here...
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `username and password` credential in jenkins, for example `database_crendential`, then use it like this :

```
environment {
    DATABASE_CREDS = credentials('database_crendential ')
}

...
sh """$mvn flyway:info \
-Dproject.host=$databaseHost \
-Dproject.port=$databasePort \
-Dproject.schema=$databaseSchema \
-Dproject.user=${DATABASE_CREDS_USR}\
-Dproject.password=${DATABASE_CREDS_PSW}\ // <--- Use a Docker secret here...
"""
```

Comment: Yes, but this way I would need to maintain the same secret in a) Jenkins and b) Docker secrets, right?

Comment: so you can run this step in a docker agent and use the secret without definig a jenkins credential.

Comment: Unfortunately our Jenkins server and its filesystem is separated from the Docker host.

Comment: it's not a problem, you have to configure the connection to your Docker host in jenkins configuration and then use agent in jenkinsfile. (https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/)

Comment: Guess I still have some problems understanding. Let's clarify this in chat? https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189204/jenkins